# My CSS will only link to my HTML page if I use the whole pathname! Why?

Tags: html, css, filepath

If I try and link my CSS to my HTML page with either cssstyle2.css ||fifastream1.0/cssstyle2.css or even %fifastream1.0%/cssstyle2.css it wont display any of the CSS on the webpage. (FF, IE, Chrome). I've uploaded my CSS page to stackoverflow before and apparently its fine.

Obviously its no good if I can only get my webpage to 'properly' work on my drive. Soo any idea's why FF, IE or Chrome cant pick up my CSS?

Been working on this for a few weeks now, as a complete beginner. Would be great help if someone could find the answer! I've searched and tried everything.

This is the link in the  of the HTML (if this helps at all)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
<link href="C:///*****/******/Desktop/FifaStream1.0/cssstyle2.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media"screen"/>
<title> Fifa Stream </title>
</head>

<body>
```

Comment: what is the full path to your page file

Comment: Users/ and then my username

Comment: you should use a relative path such as `/foo/bar.css`

Comment: Why are you using an absolute path in the first place? What's your directory structure look like?

Comment: Everything is in the same folder. Html, images and css files. But it only links if I put an absolute pathname, that's the problem.

Comment: try using ../cssstyle2.css the ../ for each parent above the root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have relative referencing, ur CSS needs to be in at least somewhat referential place. for example, if the page is in Users/whatever/index.html, your CSS would be in Users/whatever/css/style.css. Then your reference would be to "css/style.css"

A quick reference guide:

```
<!--
    ./filename or filename = same folder as page location
    ../filename = folder above that of page folder location
    /filename = root folder of project
-->
```

If your CSS file is in a completely different location than your page file, it can't possibly be found unless you provide the full path as you had to.

Comment: Iv tried that but it didnt work. So put everything in the same folder the html, images and css files etc. But when I tried to link them it didnt/wont work. unless I use the full pathname?

Comment: this does work, its basic HTML. did you seriously downvote my answer?

Comment: Thanks for you help by the way, I know thats why its really strange that it doesnt work, even my tutor doesnt understand.

Comment: just to clarify ... your page is `.../Desktop/FifaStream1.0/index.html` (or similar name) and your CSS is `.../Desktop/FifaStream1.0/cssstyle2.css`? And these are the correct filenames?

Comment: It has worked! Finally! I put ./cssstyle2.css and it works in every browser now. I dont know why it didnt do that in the first place as my tutor tried it! But Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

When everything is in the same foldre you should use the following:

```
<link href="cssstyle2.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media"screen"/>
```

When you're CSS file is in a different folder use:

```
<link href="folder/cssstyle2.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media"screen"/>
```

If your CSS file is one directory above the html file then use:

```
<link href="../cssstyle2.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media"screen"/>
```